# How to create graph with cycles without mutable data using?

Tags: ocaml, immutability, mutual-recursion

I have next code:

```
module MakeLink (Key : Map.OrderedType) = struct
   module Links = Map.Make (Key)

    type 'a t = 
      { links : 'a t Links.t;
        value : 'a
      }

    type key_t = Key.t

    let make value = 
      { links = Links.empty;
        value
      }

    let link linker ~to':linkable ~by:key = 
      { linker with links = 
        Links.add key linkable linker.links
      } 

   (* some functions for reading here *)
end
```

How to create two links linked to each other? 
I tried:

```
let join a ~with':b ~by:key = 
  let rec a' = link a ~to':b' ~by:key
      and b' = link b ~to':a' ~by:(Key.opposite key) in
  a'
```

[But it's looking like a hen that hatched from their own egg.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555440/how-to-call-two-functions-and-use-their-results-as-arguments-for-each-other?noredirect=1#comment41732916_26555440)
And my question is: How to create graph with cycles (for example: doubly-linked list) without mutable data using (in OCaml or other language)?

Comment: You can alleviate the issue by moving the links in a separate data structure (usually a matrix, which may or may not be mutable, though the former will perform better), an use then a map (or simply an array if the ids are integers) from node ids to node data. The other advantage of splitting data that way is that you can easily adapt existing algorithms and apply them on your graphs. Using arrays will lead to better use of cache locality as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a cyclically linked structure in OCaml using `let rec`.

```
# type 'a g = { links: 'a g list; value: 'a };;
type 'a g = { links : 'a g list; value : 'a; }
# let rec a = { links = [b]; value = 5; }
      and b = { links = [a]; value = 6; };;
val a : int g =
  {links =
  ... many strange lines of output ...
val b : int g =
  {links =
  ... many more strange lines of output ...
```

However once you have such a structure, it's very difficult to write functions that can process it in useful ways. I don't think you can do this kind of programming in OCaml, an eager language. In practice you have to use mutable fields for your links.

I have no experience with this but it seems more possible to do such processing in Haskell, a non-eager language.

Comment: It is possible in OCaml, but needs excess code duplications.

Comment: It would be cool to see some code that takes a simple cycle and a new element and returns a new cycle with the element added.